# how to pass complex object parameters in postman?

Tags: c#, json, rest, postman

my c# api takes two parameters, one complex object and one string:

```
[HttpPost, Route("paramtester")]
public string paramtester(people user, string message) {
    return user.name + message;}
```

how do I pass by a json object in the body? I have tried passing in a serial json object which doesn't work at all:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 30,
        "country": "USA"
    },
    "message": "Hello, World!"
}
```

this will return:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-40ce97917410bdcff73bb4d8737ed944-2c7f4bf20348d6b7-00",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "address": [
            "The address field is required."
        ],
        "message": [
            "The message field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `user` would be passed as json (but it would be root element) and `message` as querystring ... as you didn't say to controller to do it other way ... you should rather create new root model with both parameters and let the method take only this as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 correct approaches:

1. create a request object that contains a complex object `user` and a silple string `message`

   ```cs
   public class ParamTesterRequest
   {
      public People User {get; set;}
      public string Message {get; set;}
   }
   ```

   So your web API become

   ```cs
    [HttpPost("paramtester")]
    public string ParamTester(ParamTesterRequest request)
    {
       return request.User.Name + request.Message;
    }
   ```
2. the other one is as said by Selvin, use the complex parameter `user` from body and the other one as query parameter. So your web API become

   ```cs
    [HttpPost("paramtester")]
    public string ParamTester([FromQuery] string message, [FromBody] People user)
    {
       return user.Name + message;
    }
   ```

NOTE: the first answer is that it is the simplest and cleanest

Comment: I didn't said that op should do this but that is done by default (first parameter is from body and other from query string) so with ops current code he should eventually send data this way

Answer (score 0):

You should create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that includes both:

```cs
    public sealed class MyDto
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("user")]
        public User user { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("message")]
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class User
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("age")]
        public int age { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
```

Then add `[FromBody]` to the endpoint:

```cs
[HttpPost, Route("paramtester")]
public string paramtester([FromBody] MyDto myDto) {
    return myDto.Name + myDto.Message;}
```